# Sub domain and HTACCESS not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dns, subdomain

So we have a php page `www.example.com` with a button which redirects to `www.subdomain.example.com`

We are facing following issues with sub domain and htaccess:

1. When we use `<a href ="www.subdomain.example.com">button</a>` the
   media queries and favicons do not work
2. When we user `<a href ="www.example.com/folder/index2">button</a>` where the sub domain code is, the URL masking doesn't work (but media queries and favicons work perfectly)
3. We have HTACCESS configured such that .php is hidden in URL and `www.example.com/folder/index2` is masked by `www.subdomain.example.com`
4. Throughout the sub domain title also doesn't work

We have following setup in GoDaddy:

1. `subdomain` -> `www.subdomain`
2. `www.subdomain` -> `www.example.com/folder/index2`
3. `example.com` -> `www.example.com`

The sub domain code is in `example.com/folder/`

We are trying to understand how the mapping works as code is working perfectly fine without sub domain but messes up when we redirect the URL.

---

Main index file

```
<html>

<head>

    <?php
        $dir = "favicons/";
            $files = array();
                if ($handle = opendir($dir))
                {
                    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
                    {
                        $files[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            $icon = $files[rand(2,count($files)-1)];
        echo '<LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="favicons/'.$icon.'">';
    ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link href="assets/css/main2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
    <img href=""src="images/bg.jpg">
    <br>
    <br> 


    <a href="http://www.subdomain.example.com" class ="button"><button class="bt">button</button></a>

    </div>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="assets/js/main.js">
                </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Index2 file which is in the folder pointed by subdomain

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <?php
        $dir = "../favicons/";
            $files = array();
                if ($handle = opendir($dir))
                {
                    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
                    {
                        $files[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            $icon = $files[rand(2,count($files)-1)];
        echo '<LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="../favicons/'.$icon.'">';
    ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link href="../assets/css/main1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h1>random text</h1>
            <br>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="../assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="../assets/js/skel.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="../assets/js/main.js">
                </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

HTACCESS file

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

ErrorDocument 400     www.example.com/Error-404
ErrorDocument 401     www.example.com/Error-404
ErrorDocument 403     www.example.com/Error-404
ErrorDocument 404     www.example.com/Error-404
ErrorDocument 500     www.example.com/Error-404
```

Comment: Please add the Code that you have so far. And describe the point here you stuck. BTW `<a href ="www....` is invalid code it should be `<a href ="http://www....` or stating from the domain like '/' or `/folder/index`

Comment: @Webdesigner Updated the code in question.

Comment: @Webdesigner surprisingly the CSS and JavaScript is working fine on desktop, but messes up in mobile. Favicons don't work anywhere.

I think the issue is with subdomain.